# Difference between two expressions in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

Suppose we have the following Alloy model:

```
abstract sig Season {}
one sig Spring, Summer, Fall, Winter extends Season {}

abstract sig Student {
  bornIn: one Season
}

abstract sig Freshman, Sophomore extends Student {}
one sig John, Walter extends Freshman {}
one sig Sarah extends Sophomore {}

pred isCompatibleWith(s1, s2: Student) {
  s1.bornIn = s2.bornIn
}
```

I want to say that Sarah the Sophomore mustn't be compatible with any Freshman.

```
fact {
  not Sarah.isCompatibleWith[Freshman]
}
```

Alloy is satisfied with my syntax.  I add an assertion:

```
assert WhyDoesThisNotHold {
 not Sarah.isCompatibleWith[John]
}
```

But Alloy finds a counter-example: Sarah and John are both born in the Summer!

Whereas when I change the `fact` to this, Alloy does not find a counter-example:

```
fact {
  no f: Freshman | Sarah.isCompatibleWith[f]
}
```

What's the difference between the two syntaxes, and why does the first one not work as I intend?  (And since it's valid Alloy syntax, what's it actually saying?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first fact doesn't behave as you expect because you call the predicate `isCompatibleWith` with the set of all `Freshman` as parameter, however this predicate is not meant to check the compatibility between two sets of students. (it could be by replacing the `=` symbol by the intersection operator`&` and check that the resulting set is empty.

I will now show you how this fact doesn't prevent John and Sarah to be compatible.
Suppose that Sarah and John are born in Summer and Walter in Winter, then the fact holds because  :

```
not Sarah.isCompatibleWith[Freshman]  =  not Sarah.isCompatibleWith[Walter+John]
                                      =  not Sarah.bornIn=(Walter+John).bornIn
                                      =  not Summer = (Summer+Winter)
                                      =  not false
                                      =  true
```